# In light of Word of God, can this Star Wars question be reworked?

Tags: discussion

(First Meta post, prompted by AncientSwordRage; if I've done something wrong in the question, it's not intentional, and please don't hesitate to fix it)

Jarwin asked a question earlier on whether [Star Wars should have ended after the prequels](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113310/should-star-wars-have-ended-after-return-of-the-jedi)

Without putting words in Jarwin's mouth, it seems as though he disagrees with the saga continuing -- because a satisfying end has been reached, if nothing else. It's also looking for opinion, and has been closed as such.

However, I think the essence of the question can be saved and made into a good question: something along the lines of, as AncientSwordRage suggested, "did Lucas intend to continue the story beyond VI" or something like "are the events and intended stories of the original six movies concluded by episode VI" (a far better proposal than my own of "ain't it done yet?")

I would still argue that's quite opinion based; however @NikolaiDante has an answer with quotes from Lucas himself that weigh in on the matter. In light of this, should / could the question be reworked to fit in our guidelines while still keeping the essence of the question?

Comment: Lucas has made so many contradictory statements about this subject that his word has no more value than the subjective opinion of someone who is uninvolved.

Comment: @user45623 ha indeed so. The new question got marked as dupe in the end and there's an obscene amount of conflicting quotes even in one answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No because those changes would invalidate the other answer. Post your reworked version as a new question, and link back to the closed one as inspiration.

Comment: It certainly wouldn't invalidate NikolaiDante's answer (not if we go with the "did Lucas..." suggestion) (the other answer is in discussion of whether it interpreted the question correctly; I'm not familiar enough with Star Wars to address that myself) Would the new question not be marked as duplicate to this one, as NikolaiDante has provided the answer there?

Comment: This is a much better idea

Comment: @mac no it shouldn't do

Comment: Preferably inviting Nikolai to answer your new question.

Comment: @SQB, indeed. I missed the connection that the existing question would be closed at the time of the new one.